# Weirdness with mongoengine ReferenceField

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, mongoengine

This is a puzzling problem that's difficult even to name, let alone describe. I'll start with the essential facts and then give what background information might be relevant.

Consider two mongoengine document models:

```python
class Bar(Document):
    # ...
    # field definitions
    # ...
    def bar_func(self):
        pass  # ...or some arbitrary code


class Foo(Document):
    bar = ReferenceField(Bar)
```

The following is **inconsistently** producing an `AttributeError` on our production server:

```python
# Assume foo_id references a valid Foo document in Mongo
# and that its 'bar' reference is to a valid Bar document.
foo = Foo.objects.with_id(foo_id)
foo.bar.bar_func()  # <-- AttributeError on 'bar_func'
```

If I place debugging code right before the location of the error, evaluating `type(foo.bar)` as a string produces `<class 'bson.dbref.DBRef'>`.  Obviously a `DBRef` doesn't have a `bar_func` attribute, but why is a `DBRef` being returned instead of an instance of `Bar`?

Further debugging code shows that the following condition is failing in the `ReferenceField.__get__` function in `mongoengine/fields.py`:

```python
if isinstance(value, (pymongo.dbref.DBRef)):
        value = _get_db().dereference(value)
```

But `(pymongo.dbref.DBRef)` is actually `bson.dbref.DBRef`, which seems to be the same as `type(foo.bar)`!  Why does `isinstance` fail?

This is where things get *really* weird:

```python
id(type(foo.bar)) == id(bson.dbref.DBRef)  # <-- Evaluates to False!
```

In other words, `type(foo.bar)` is a *different* `bson.dbref.DBRef` than the one obtained by referencing `bson.dbref.DBRef` directly.  In fact, inspecting the `__dict__` of these two types shows different memory locations for their functions and properties.

*Note:* I'll call the type returned by `type(foo.bar)` `fooDBRef` for convenience below, to distinguish it from the type referenced by `bson.dbref.DBRef`.

To debug further, I modified the `DBRef` code to add a metaclass that inspects the system modules at the time the `DBRef` type is created, and stores a list of the IDs of those modules in an extra class attribute of `DBRef`.  The results show that the set of modules in existence when `fooDBRef` is created is *entirely distinct* from the set of modules in existence when the bare `bson.dbref.DBRef` type is created.  All module IDs for one are different from all module IDs for the other.

Some possibly relevant factors:

- The server on which this error occurs runs mod_wsgi under Apache.
- The server runs two different Django sites under wsgi (call them `site_a` and `site_b`).
- Foo is defined in `site_a.foo_app.models` and Bar is defined in `site_b.bar_app.models`.
- `site_a` settings.py has `site_b.bar_app` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- The requests that produce the error are handled by `site_a`.
- There were `site_b.*` modules in `sys.modules` when `fooDBRef` was created, but no `site_a.*` modules.  The reverse is true for `bson.dbref.DBRef`.
- After an `httpd reload` the error sometimes goes away for a little while, and returns sometime within 0-10 attempts.

**Can anyone help me figure out what is causing `fooDBRef` to be different from `bson.dbref.DBRef`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using embedded mode or daemon mode of mod_wsgi? If using daemon mode of mod_wsgi are you delegating each site to a different daemon process group and then in turn forcing the application to run in main Python interpreter?

It may be the case that mongodb Python client module may not work properly in Python sub interpreters, especially when the module is used at the same time in a different sub interpreter of the same process.

So, you may have to run each site in separate daemon process group using WSGIDaemonProcess/WSGIProcessGroup and then force the user of the Python main interpreter using WSGIApplicationGroup with argument of '%{GLOBAL}'.

Note that when forcing use of main interpreter for both sites, you can no longer use embedded mode, or have them both run in same daemon process group. Thus why you need to force each to run in separate daemon process group.

Comment: We were using embedded mode.  I switched to daemon mode, adding the WSGIDaemonProcess, WSGIProcessGroup, and WSGIApplicationGroup directives to the VirtualHost entries, and the WSGISocketPrefix directive to the root level of the config.  And it seems to have worked!  At least, the error hasn't happened yet, and normally it would have by this point.  I will wait a day or so to make sure it's gone and then accept the answer.  Thanks for the help!